# how to group the object list in an array based on its matching property values in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, grouping

I have an array of object as follow

```
var arrlst =[
{id:[1],Name:'john',Country:['US]',Unit:['AB'],Department:['Dep1']},
{id:[2],Name:'John',Country:['UK'],Unit:['AB'],Department:['Dep1']},
{id:[3],Name:'John',Country:['AB'],Unit:['AB'],Department:['Dep2']},
{id:[4],Name:'Angel',Country:['CN'],Unit:['CD'],Department:['Dep1']},
{id:[5],Name:'John',Country:['US'],Unit:['AB'],Department:['Dep1']},
{id:[6],Name:'John',Country:['US'],Unit:['CD'],Department:['Dep3']},
{id:[7],Name:'Angel',Country:['CN'],Unit:['CB'],Department:['Dep1']},
{id:[8],Name:'Angel',Country:['CN'],Unit:['CC'],Department:['Dep1']},
{id:[9],Name:'Mike',Country:['IN'],Unit:['CC'],Department:['Dep2']},
{id:[10],Name:'Mike',Country:['IN'],Unit:['CC'],Department:['Dep1']},
{id:[11],Name:'Mike',Country:['IN'],Unit:['CB'],Department:['Dep1']}
]
```

[Table view using ng-repeat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJTt1.png)

I want to group it by two matching column values (either **Country** and **Unit** or **Unit** and **Department**) for each **Name**.
The resulting array should look as follow.

```
var resultArr =[
{id:[1,2],Name:'John',Country:['US','UK'],Unit:['AB'],Department:['Dep1']},
{id:[3],Name:'John',Country:['IN'],Unit:['AB'],Department:['Dep2']},
{id:[4,7,8],Name:'Angel',Country:['CN'],Unit:['CD','CC','CB'],Department:['Dep1']},
{id:[5],Name:'John',Country:['US'],Unit:['CB'],Department:['Dep1']},
{id:[6],Name:'John',Country:['US'],Unit:['CD'],Department:['Dep3']},
{id:[9,10],Name:'Mike',Country:['IN'],Unit:['CC'],Department:['Dep2','Dep2']},
{id:[11],Name:'Mike',Country:['IN'],Unit:['CB'],Department:['Dep1']}
]
```

[Resulting table view using ng-repeat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmKjE.png)

I'm trying the following code. but sometimes it misses some array to get grouped.

```
scope.getgrouped = function (arrlst) {

    var Names = [];
    //get Names 
    angular.forEach(arrlst, function (value, key) {
        if (Names.indexOf(value.Name) === -1) Names.push(value.Name);
    });
    var resultArr = []

    angular.forEach(Names, function (Name) {
        //get record  for the current Name
        var lstcurrent = [];
        lstcurrent.length = 0;
        angular.forEach(arrlst, function (row) {
            if (row.Name === Name) {
                lstcurrent.push(row);
            }
        });



        if (lstcurrent.length === 1)
            resultArr.push(lstcurrent[0]);
        else {

            for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

                if (lstcurrent.length > 0 && lstcurrent[0]["id"].length > 1) {
                    resultArr.push(lstcurrent[0]);
                    lstcurrent.splice(0, 1);

                }
                if (lstcurrent.length === 1) {
                    resultArr.push(lstcurrent[0]);
                    break;
                }

                for (var j = 1; j < lstcurrent.length; j++) {


                    if ((lstcurrent[0].Country.indexOf(lstcurrent[j].Country[0]) !== -1) && (lstcurrent[0].Unit.indexOf(lstcurrent[j].Unit[0]) !== -1)  && i == 0) {

                        if (lstcurrent[0].Department.indexOf(lstcurrent[j].Department[0]) === -1) lstcurrent[0].Department.push(lstcurrent[j].Department[0]);
                        lstcurrent[0].id.push(lstcurrent[j].id[0]);
                        lstcurrent.splice(j, 1);
                        j = j - 1;
                        continue;


                    }

                    //Country + Department
                    else if ((lstcurrent[0].Country.indexOf(lstcurrent[j].Country[0]) !== -1) && (lstcurrent[0].Department.indexOf(lstcurrent[j].Department[0]) !== -1) && i === 1) {

                        if (lstcurrent[0].Unit.indexOf(lstcurrent[j].Unit[0]) === -1) lstcurrent[0].Unit.push(lstcurrent[j].Unit[0]);
                        lstcurrent[0].id.push(lstcurrent[j].id[0]);
                        lstcurrent.splice(j, 1);
                        j = j - 1;
                        continue;


                    } //Unit + Department
                    else if ((lstcurrent[0].Unit.indexOf(lstcurrent[j].Unit[0]) !== -1) && (lstcurrent[0].Department.indexOf(lstcurrent[j].Department[0]) !== -1) && i === 2) {

                        if (lstcurrent[0].Country.indexOf(lstcurrent[j].Country[0]) === -1) lstcurrent[0].Country.push(lstcurrent[j].Country[0]);
                        lstcurrent[0].id.push(lstcurrent[j].id[0]);
                        lstcurrent.splice(j, 1);
                        j = j - 1;
                        continue;




                    } else if (i > 2) {

                        if (lstcurrent.length === 1)

                        {
                            resultArr.push(lstcurrent[0]);


                        } else {
                            resultArr.push(lstcurrent[j - 1]);
                            lstcurrent.splice(j - 1, 1);

                            i = 0;
                            break;

                        }

                    }

                }

            }
        }

    })};
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  SO(StackOverflow) is not a place where you pay money and someone solves your tasks but help you to find the issues in your code.  Please, post relevant code with your tries.

Comment: @MaximShoustin.. Thanks.. I have already updated my query with sample code snippet.